# Schengen visa application while in Europe on a ship

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, sea-travel

I am currently in Naples as a crew member onboard a ship and due to disembark soon to return home to South Africa.

Is it possible to apply online or at an embassy here in Naples for a Schengen visa in order to travel Europe?

Comment: Are you permanent crew or in a supernumerary capacity?

Comment: @GayotFow does it matter?

Comment: @phoog it has a bearing on whether the OP can benefit from the answer below.

Answer (score 13):

The general rule is that Schengen visas cannot be issued at the border.

However, there are special exceptions from this ([Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810), article 36 and annex IX) for seamen who leave service on a ship in a Schengen port and need to transit the Schengen area to return to their home country.

Such a visa must be arranged through the shipping company (who has to make certain guarantees) -- contact your employer ASAP and let them manage the paperwork.

Comment: actually, do you "apply online" for schengen visas (much like the yank's "ESTAs" or whatever) ....... or does it not work like that?

Comment: Schengen visa applications are more conventional, judged visa applications, in contrast to the pretty much entirely automated ESTA process.

Comment: @JoeBlow Schengen doesn't have anything like the ESTA. People from friendly low risk countries get to come with no visa at all. People from less friendgly or higher risk countries generally have to apply for a traditional visa in advance. Visa on arrival is only allowed for in a few special cases.

Comment: @PeterGreen there is such a system in the works, however: [etias](https://www.google.com/search?q=etias).

Comment: The governing part of the visa code is article 36, along with article 35 by reference; Annex IX just lays out the forms and some details of the procedure.